# Create subclass from parent view Vaadin 8

Tags: jakarta-ee, vaadin, crud

I am working on a CrudView at Vaadin 8, is it possible to create a subclass in parent's view?

What I want to achieve is in `Run`crud View have a ComboBox binded to `Dummy` properties.

```
class Run{
  String name;
  Dummy ee;
} 

class Dummy{
  Exercise exercise;
  Stadium stadium;
}
```

Comment: Can you give some details which Vaadin components you are using or planning to use for the view and are you using the Binder like here: https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/datamodel/datamodel-forms.html

Comment: If you could upload a bit more code showing us what it is you're trying to do. I don't completely understand what it is that you're asking